# what does this line means? Can somebody help me by explaining consumer.Received += (model, ea)

Tags: c#

[image]

this is snip of code. I m not getting "consumer.Received += (model ,ea) =>

Comment: Please post code instead of images.

Comment: Look up Lambda. The => operator is usually spoken as 'goes to'.

Answer (score 3):

As of the [docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/v1.4.0/rabbitmq-dotnet-client-1.4.0-net-2.0-htmldoc/type-RabbitMQ.Client.Events.BasicDeliverEventHandler.html) `Received` is an event within the `EventingBasicConsumer`-class. This means that you can register for the event by adding an event-handler to it.

```
consumer.Recieved += (model, args) => { /* 
    do whatever you want when the event is triggered 
*/};
```

This is some portion of code (more accurate a delegate) that is executed when the event occurs. In your special case you also get some arguments from the event to appropriately react on that event. The first is of type `IBasicConsumer` and the second of type `BasicDeliverEventArgs`. Thus the following is identical to the code I´ve written above:

```
consumer.Recieved += (IBasicConsumer model, BasicDeliverEventArgs args) => { /* 
    do whatever you want when the event is triggered 
*/};
```

While you often can omit the first one as it´s not needed the second one holds information the caller of the event (the Rabbit-framework in your case) applied to that delegate. So you can use it and display it in a `MessageBox` for instance.

```
var body = args.Body;
```

Alternativly to using an anonymous method (a method without a name as shown above) you can surely use a named one:

```
consumer.Recieved += MyHandler;

private void MyHandler(IBasicConsumer model, BasicDeliverEventArgs args)
{
    // your stuff here
}
```

Doing so has the advantage that you can easily remove the handler.

```
consumer.Recieved -= MyHandler;
```

Answer (score 0):

So your question boils down to what does `consumer.Received += (model, ea) => {stuff}` do?  Its a Lambda function..

well the Received is an event, which clearly has 2 properties, for which the coder has named them model and ea. Which they they use in {stuff}

Previously you could/would have written (and Im making up variable types here but)

```
consume.Received += mycall;

void mycall(String model, Mything ea)
{
  stuff;
}
```

There are however disadvantages of the lamda, while you can add them on the fly, its not so easy to remove.. where as the older style you can do consume.Received -= mycall;

Comment: It's called Lambda

Comment: Sorry, I din't want to offend you. But it is a very common mistake and I wanted to point it out to you

Comment: It is a mistake I often make as non-dyslectic, so don't feel offended :)

Comment: `consumer.Received ==` should be `consumer.Received +=` (it added the event handler, it doesn't compare it)

Comment: yeah cant type today I guess